# Bootstrap slide event not working inside AJAX success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

This is my code, 'slide' event inside AJAX success call.

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#my_container').html(data);
    // I am getting' #mycarousel' successfully in to #my_container
    $('#mycarousel').bind('slid', function(e) {
        console.log('hi');
    }
    // tried 'slid.bs.carousel' too, no change.
    // btw, I can see my 'slid' function under event listeners for that element.
    // when I paste the above binding code in console again it shows the element too.
});
```

I want to print the 'hi' to console on slid event, which is not working now.

Thanks

Comment: I just want to print "console.log('hi');"

Comment: here's a working fiddle of what you're asking: http://jsfiddle.net/faw242a8/ your problem is probably elsewhere in the code. Wait i see, you are loading the carousel via ajax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether you have **multiple versions of jquery libraries** loaded in the page.

Use `$.fn.jquery` to find the loaded version and cross check it with the jquery version you have included and see both are same.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Just checked, accidently used jquery versions 2.2.x twice(one directly and another one included in another js file).
Solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After loading the carousel dynamically, you have to initialize it (as [androbin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1558028/androbin) suggested):

```
  $('#my_container').html(data);

  $("#mycarousel").carousel();

  $('#mycarousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
      console.log('slide event!');
  });

  $('#mycarousel').bind('slid', function (e) {
      console.log("slid event!");
  });
```

Here you can see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/faw242a8/1/

Make sure the html you are pulling in via ajax contains a valid carousel.

Reference: [Carousel - Bootstrap](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/#via-javascript)

Comment: Yeah when I checked with my code by placing my html and js in jsfiddle it works. So I think the issue lies elsewhere. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: you definitely need to run `$("#mycarousel").carousel();` after loading the carousel dynamically. Try that before looking elsewhere.

Comment: I think this is the problem - when i check "$.fn.carousel" in the console, it's undefined. Any idea why?